# Using redirects inside a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

This seems like I'm missing something obvious but I can't get redirects (>) to work in a .bat / .cmd file.

From the command line, this works as expected and sends the output and error streams to the log file:

```
doxygen doxygen.config 2>&1 > doxygen.log
```

Putting the exact same line inside a batch file and running it doesn't work however.  It looks like it tries to write the entire command to the log file rather than execute it and then loops??

How do I get output redirects to work inside a bat / cmd file?  In case it makes a difference, I am using Win7 and have tried from cmd and powershell.

Comment: Some pixie dust should do the trick.

Comment: What is your batch file called? Where is it stored and where do you call it from?

Comment: @AndriyM doxygen.cmd.  In the same folder as doxygen.config.  The doxygen executable is on PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the batch script is calling itself. I would suggest you explicitly specify the extension for the executable your script is calling:

```
doxygen.exe doxygen.config 2>&1 > doxygen.log
```

Comment: Thank you and yes, I feel like an idiot now :)  For some reason I also had to switch the last two parts so 2>&1 was on the end but now it works.